# Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: ethash is only supported as a historical component of already merged networks

Tags: go-ethereum

When trying to start nodes in my computer receiving a `Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: ethash is only supported as a historical component of already merged networks` error.

This had worked for me before, but I've tried to connect another peer from another computer, when I noticed the versions of Geth aren't the same, so I updated my version and it stopped working since then.

I'm using the same --networkid for all nodes, same genesis.json for all of them.

This is my command for running it:

```shell
geth --datadir data/node1 --port 30304 --nodiscover --authrpc.port 8547 --networkid 22345 console 2>console1.log
```

This is my genesis.json file:

```json
{
"config": {
        "chainId": 10,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
},
"alloc"      : {},
"coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"difficulty" : "0x20000",
"extraData"  : "",
"gasLimit": "0x2fefd8",
"nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

I've tried deleting the nodes folders and console logs and re-initiating them (with same genesis.json file), I've tried restarting the computer, updating Geth again using brew.

On another computer (MacOS as well) in the same network the node is able to run, same Geth version, same command used to start the node.

I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.4; geth version `geth version 1.12.0-stable`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethash was the proof of work mining algorithm which seems to be turned off in the latest version. Try the 2nd latest release (Geth 1.11.6) and it should work.

from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.12.0 :

> The v1.12 release family drops support for proof-of-work, and thus can
> not be used any more on PoW-based private chains, or as an upstream
> library for projects depending on ethash PoW (#27178, #27147).

more info: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pow/mining-algorithms/ethash/

Comment: That worked! thank you very much.